# Drawing quadrant shape with cv2 in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, svg

I'm extracting door shapes with [Cubicasa5k dataset](https://zenodo.org/record/2613548#.Y9Iha3ZBxaQ) but I don't know how svg draws quarter rounds.

Extracted some nodes of svg files with xml encoding, I found that it had a dictionary including 'd' key and value under of "Panel" id tree node like :

```
{'d': 'M825.47,986.05 q0.00,-72.92 72.92,-72.92 l0.00,72.92Z'}
```

[It draws like this quarter round on svg image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Mlg.png)

I want to draw that shape on raster image with cv2 in Python with that dictionary value.

Read [article about 'd' commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) but I'm still confused.

How can I draw it?

Comment: Here is link: https://pyquestions.com/how-can-i-draw-half-circle-in-opencv

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I hope I understood that d command of svg clearly now

That arc shape is Bézier curve, and it is drawn concavely based on the outer point, not on the centripetal point.

According to the example above ('M825.47,986.05 q0.00,-72.92 72.92,-72.92 l0.00,72.92Z'), it means drawing process following this:

1. The starting point of arc shape(called Bézier curve) is **(825.47, 986.05)**.
2. The drawn reference point exists at a position shifted only to the y-axis. So the reference point is (825.47+0.00, 986.05-72.92) = **(825.47, 913.13)**
3. And the end point of arc shape is set following calculation about starting point like 2 : (825.47+72.92, 986.05-72.92) = **(898.39, 913.13)**
4. Drawing door shape finishes with drawing straight line that starts from the end point of the curve and ends with l code, it points (898.39+0.00, 913.13+72.92) = **(898.39, 986.05)**

Simply speaking, the door shape is drawn with arc and straight line, arc starts from left bottom and ends right top, then straight line starts from that right top and ends right bottom.

So if using cv2, should call [cv2.ellipse](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69), and set center point from process 4 above, axes(same value will show circle-like shape, so it's radius) from q command above, startangle and endangle(it differs from command above)